# Assign to a T-SQL variable from a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to assign some variables inside a query that uses `CASE` statements for it's columns. Not quite sure how to do this, having trouble finding the right syntax.

This is what I have so far, but it's got syntax errors.

```
 -- set @theID and @theName with their appropriate values
 select top (1) 
 @theID = (Case when B.ID IS NULL then A.ID else B.ID END) ,
 @theName = (Case when B.Name IS NULL then A.Name else B.Name END) 
 from B left join A on A.ID = B.ID where ...
```

What's the correct place/way to stick those variables in there?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how "it's not quite working"?

Comment: I'm putting my variable assignment in the wrong place and it causes a syntax error. I'm not sure where/how to put the variable assignment.

Comment: What you have posted works well for me. Your issue may not be in the assignment, but the actual code. Can you post the actual code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The example you've given should work.  You can assign to variables from a case statement.  Just pretend that the entire CASE..WHEN..THEN..ELSE..END block is a field.  Here is a generic example:

```
declare @string1 nvarchar(100) = null
declare @string2 nvarchar(100) = null

select
  @string1 = case when 1=1 then 'yes' else 'no' end
 ,@string2 = case when 1=0 then 'yes' else 'no' end

print 'string1 = ' + @string1
print 'string2 = ' + @string2
```

Gives:

```
string1 = yes
string2 = no
```

Can you tell us what specific error(s) you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do this more easily using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`:

```
select top (1) 
 @theID = ISNULL(B.ID, A.ID),
 @theName = ISNULL(B.Name, A.Name),
 from B left join A on A.ID = B.ID where ...
```

Comment: This is true in his particular case, but does not answer the question.

Comment: I disagree.  Getting the desired functionality working while improving the code seems like an excellent answer.  Also, his original code didn't appear to be broken...

Comment: I think you might be biased as to what might make an excellent answer to this question ;) If he'd asked the question in a broader way (i.e. stating his goals rather than asking questions about a particular implemention), then I'd agree with you, but he asked about assigning values to variables using a `case` statement, which is a perfectly valid use case that, in *this particular case* can be replaced with a different solution. Recommending alternatives is certainly good, but the original question needs to be addressed first.

Comment: `I think you might be biased as to what might make an excellent answer to this question` well maybe ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @SmallBlindSeatId INT  
DECLARE @BigBlindSeatId INT  
DECLARE @DealerSeatId INT  
DECLARE @NextTurn INT  

SELECT @DealerSeatId=( CASE WHEN BlindsInfo=1 THEN SeatId ELSE @DealerSeatId END ),
@SmallBlindSeatId=( CASE WHEN BlindsInfo=2 THEN SeatId ELSE @SmallBlindSeatId END),
@BigBlindSeatId=( CASE WHEN BlindsInfo=3 THEN SeatId ELSE @BigBlindSeatId END),
@NextTurn=( CASE WHEN NEXTTURN=1 THEN SeatId ELSE @NextTurn END)

FROM ABC WHERE TESTCASEID=1

PRINT(@DealerSeatId)

PRINT(@SmallBlindSeatId)

PRINT(@BigBlindSeatId)

PRINT (@NextTurn)
```